# Gscript code to send dummy parameters to google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to send the dummy values using Gscript code to my google spreadsheet.

Code:

```
 function doGet(e) { 
  Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );  // view parameters
  var result = 'Ok'; // assume success
  if (e.parameter == 'undefined') 
   {
    result = 'No Parameters';
   }
  else {
    var sheet_id = 'google sheet ID /d<ID>/edit';       // 
Spreadsheet ID
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id).getActiveSheet();
    var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;                        
    var rowData = [];
    rowData[0] = new Date();                                            // 
Timestamp in column A
    for (var param in e.parameter) {
      Logger.log('In for loop, param=' + param);
      var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
      Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
      switch (param) {
        case 'tempC': //Parameter
          rowData[1] = value; //Value in column B
          result = 'Written on column B';
          break;
        case 'tempF': //Parameter
          rowData[2] = value; //Value in column B
          result = 'Written on column C';
          break;
        case 'humiD': //Parameter
          rowData[3] = value; //Value in column C
          result += ' ,Written on column D';
          break;  
        default:
         result = "unsupported parameter";
      }
    }
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
    // Write new row below
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
    newRange.setValues([rowData]);
  }
  // Return result of operation
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}
/**
* Remove leading and trailing single or double quotes
*/
function stripQuotes( value ) {
  return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}
//-----------------------------------------------
// End of file
//-----------------------------------------------
```

I am new with this work and whenever I am using script id URL  to post the dummy data to google spreadsheet

like below:

```js
https://script.google.com/macros/s/<*GScript ID>/exec?tempC=1&tempF=2&humiD=3
```

then the error of unsupported parameters shown at my execution screen and even Logger. logs show "undefined" message.

If someone has worked with this kind of issue before please share your advice will be a great much help.

[image]

Comment: logs screenshot and execution transcript screenshot

Comment: I think that if Web Apps is correctly deployed, in your script, when users access to the endpoint including the query parameters of ``tempC=1&tempF=2&humiD=3``, ``Written on column B`` is returned and the value of ``date, 1, 2, 3`` is put to the spreadsheet. So as a solution, how about redeploying Web Apps as new version? By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. If this was not the direct solution for your issue, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi, TheMaster I have shared the screenshot as well as log message shows "Undefined", and Thanks Tanaike I did it with the newer version also but still the message shows "unsupported parameters"

Comment: @var No you haven't. I asked for Logger logs and execution transcript.

Comment: @varul jain I'm really sorry. In my environment, I cannot replicate your situation. So for example, when you request to the Web Apps using curl, what result do you get?